# html <a> download link make browser not responding

Tags: php, html, download

i want to download .pdf file from direktori /assets/images/myfile.pdf in my sites direktori. and try it using  download link but id didnt work then my browser not responding and i have to kill the sites connection, i'm using Chrome. How can i fix this? here's my code

```
<a href="/assets/images/myfile.pdf" download="myfile"></a>
```

Comment: What do other browsers do?

Comment: What is your URL of this page?

Comment: Be sure that pdf file exist, and path to is absolute path starting from `http://FULL_PAGE_URL/assets/images/myfile.pdf`

Comment: what is your site url?

Comment: example my site url is https://example.com

Comment: then check my answer . it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your site url `example.com` then use this code. it is tested , for testing

put url in browser http://example.com/assets/images/myfile.pdf , replace example.com using your site url

```
<a href="http://example.com/assets/images/myfile.pdf" download="myfile">Download</a>
```

if site url is http://stackoverflow.com then replace it using this and make url your myfile exit in this location.

hope it will work

Comment: thanks for your answer,but i'm little confused with "replace it using this and make url your myfile exit in this location" part, can you explain it briefly

Comment: if your site url pandu.com then 

<a href="http://pandu.com/assets/images/myfile.pdf" download="myfile">Download</a>

Comment: and make sure your file exit in this location

Comment: this is my final code but it didnt work either <li><a href="pandu.com/assets/images/peta.pdf" download="peta"><span class="icon destinasi"></span><?php print t('Peta') ?></a></li> the pdf file not downloaded

Comment: thanks for your answer,it works! i have to put all my path direktori like sites/all/themes/assets/images/peta.pdf and it works perfectly